# Azure Pipelines - "While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key" when setting variables

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a strange problem that I can't seem to get my head around. I am trying to define some variables for use as part of the job that will deploy bicep files via Azure CLI and execute PowerShell tasks.

I get this validation error when I try and execute the pipeline:  `While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key`
The line that it refers to is: `- name: managementResourceDNSPrivateResolverName`

On the research that I have done on this problem, it sounds like an indentation problem but on the face of it, it seems to look fine.

```
jobs:
- job: 'Deploy_Management_Resources'
  pool: 
    vmImage: ${{ parameters.buildAgent }}
  variables:
    - name: managementResourceDNSPrivateResolverName
      value: 'acme-$[ lower(parameters['environmentCode']) ]-$[ lower(variables['resourceLocationShort']) ]-private-dns-resolver'
    - name: managementResourceGroupManagement 
      value: 'acme-infrastructure-rg-management'
    - name: managementResourceRouteTableName
      value: 'acme-$[ lower(variables['subscriptionCode']) ]-$[ lower(variables['resourceLocationShort']) ]-route-table'
    - name: managementResourceVirtualNetworkName
      value: 'acme-$[ lower(variables['subscriptionCode']) ]-$[ lower(variables['resourceLocationShort']) ]-vnet-internal-mng'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message `...parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key` is usually a side-effect of malformed yaml. You'll see if often with variables if you have mixed formats of arrays and property elements

```yaml
variables: # an array of objects
  # variable group reference object
  - group: myvariablegroup
  
  # variable template reference object
  - template: my-variables.yml

  # variable object
  - name: myVariable
    value: 'value1'

  # variable shorthand syntax
  myVariable: 'value1'  # this fails because it's a property instead of an array element
```

While it doesn't appear that the sample you've provided is malformed, I am curious about the use of `$[ ]` which is a *runtime expression*.  The expression `$[ lower(parameters['environmentcode']) ]` refers to `parameters` which is are only available at *compile time*.

Change:

`$[ lower(parameters['environmentCode']) ]` to `${{ lower(parameters.environmentCode) }}`

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I had been using the syntax you have suggested originally except when it is executed the variables don't seem to have a value so I end up with.

acme---route-table
instead of acme-dev01-uks-route-table

The values it should have should be coming from the Azure Pipelines variable group that is referenced when calling this .yml file as a job

Comment: Hi Johubb, I tested on my side and confirm setting the value as acme-${{ lower(parameters.environmentCode) }}-${{ lower(variables.resourceLocationShort) }}-private-dns-resolver works well. Just as a remind of [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks for your kindness :-).